# Get lines between pattern1 OR get lines that match pattern2 - sed/awk

Tags: regex, awk, sed

I have a file of the format:

```
PATTERN2
PATTERN1
text I want
more text I want ...
PATTERN1
text don't want
text don't want
text don't want
PATTERN2
PATTERN1
text I want
more text I want ...
PATTERN1
text don't want
text don't want
text don't want
...
```

I can get the text between occurances of PATTERN1 using sed.

```
sed -n -e '/PATTERN1/,/PATTERN1/ p' my_file.txt
```

I can also get lines matching PATTERN2.

```
sed -n -e '/PATTERN2/ p' my_file.txt
```

However, I am having trouble getting lines that match either of these patterns. What I want as an output is

```
PATTERN2
PATTERN1
text I want
more text I want ...
PATTERN1
PATTERN2
PATTERN1
text I want
more text I want ...
PATTERN1
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can just append the two `-e` commands together. It will execute them both for each line

```
sed -n -e '/PATTERN1/,/PATTERN1/ p' -e '/PATTERN2/ p' my_file.txt
```

Caution: if `/PATTERN2/` matches inside `/PATTERN1/`, that line will be printed twice

There is also a more-complicated sed command that solves the above caution:

```
sed -e '/PATTERN1/,/PATTERN1/ !{
    /PATTERN2/ !d
}'
```

Between the markers don't execute delete everything but PATTERN2. In other words, outside the markers, delete everything but PATTERN2.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this awk command:

```
awk '/PATTERN1/{p=!p} p || /PATTERN1|PATTERN2/' file

PATTERN2
PATTERN1
text I want
more text I want ...
PATTERN1
PATTERN2
PATTERN1
text I want
more text I want ...
PATTERN1
```

Answer (score 0):

For maintainability, never test the same hard-coded value (e.g. `PATTERN1`) multiple times:

```
$ awk '/PATTERN1/{if (f) print; f=!f} f || /PATTERN2/' file
PATTERN2
PATTERN1
text I want
more text I want ...
PATTERN1
PATTERN2
PATTERN1
text I want
more text I want ...
PATTERN1
```

If you want to replace `PATTERN1` with `FOO` in future then with the above code you only need to make that change in one place.

Answer (score 0):

An easily readable sed version:

```
sed -n "/PATTERN2/p;/PATTERN1/,/PATTERN1/p"
```

I hope this helps.

- -n don't print by default
- /PATTERN2/ singular match string
- p print it
- /PATTERN1/ first match string
- , everything between
- /PATTERN1/ second match string
- p print it